# Python socket connection settimeout()

Tags: python, sockets, settimeout

Thank you for reading this!

So I thought if I'd use socketobject.settimeout(10), that my listener would wait 10 seconds before  reading incoming data on my socket connection through recv(), nevertheless, it doesn't pause the recv() function somehow. Did I interpret anything wrong?
Server-side code:

```
socketss = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socketss.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
socketss.bind((IP,PORT))
socketss.listen()
(sockets,ip) = socketss.accept()
sockets.settimeout(3)
while True:

   data = sockets.recv(30)
if data:
   print(data)
print(sockets.recv())
```

Client-side code:

```
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.connect((IP,PORT))

socket.send(b'30000')
socket.send(b'30000')
socket.send(b'30000')
```

Also does settimeout pause at every loop, or just once?
I appreciate any answer, have a good day:)!

Answer (score 0):

> ... that my listener would wait 10 seconds before reading incoming data on my socket connection through recv()

No. `settimeout` will wait **at most** the specified time, not **exactly** as you assume. A `recv` will return immediately when data can be read before the timeout is reached. See also [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout):

> ... If a non-zero value is given, subsequent socket operations will raise a timeout exception **if the timeout period value has elapsed before the operation has completed.**

> Also does settimeout pause at every loop

The timeout is applied for every recv.